# Restrict Access for Python when using PHP proc_open

Tags: php, python, bash, proc-open

I am working on a python online editor with interpreter.
I call the python using the php's proc_open() function.

But there is a problem that somebody apparently executed the python's shutil.rmtree() function and deleted my whole website.

How can I restrict access so that python can only access data only in a specified directory